# How can I solve Type Error: completedata.map is not a function while trying to display the data in a card on a webpage

Tags: javascript

This is my JavaScript code whereby am fetching data from an externa API which am trying to display it on a webpage using a card.

```
<script>
  fetch(
    "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appBTaX8XIvvr6zEC/tblYPd5g5k5IKIc98?api_key=##"
  ).then((data) => {
    // console.log(data)
    return data.json();
  }).then((completedata) => {
    //console.log(completedata.records[2])
    let data1 = "";
    completedata.map((values) => {
      data1 = `
        <div class="card">
            <img src=${values.avatar} alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            <p class="name">${values.Name}</p>
            <p class="occupation">${values.occupation}</p>
        </div>
      `;
    });
    document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = data1;
  }).catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
</script>
```

Comment: It doesn't appear `completedata` is an array. What does that commented line reveal if you just do `console.log(completedata)`? What is the data structure returned?

Comment: Based on the documentation I'm guessing you're getting an object back. Please also note the line _"Finally, please perform all requests to these endpoints server-side. Client-side requests are not allowed because they would expose the user's API token."_.

Comment: Probably the array that you should apply `.map` on is `completedata.records`. But you should show us how `completedata` looks like. Next issue is your `data1 =` inside the map function. On each iteration you are reassigning `data1` to the new string ignoring all the previous iterations. It had to be `data1 +=` at least.

Comment: console.log(completedata) gives me :  {records: Array(83)}

Answer (score 0):

As per clarifications in comments:

> console.log(completedata) gives me : {records: Array(83)}

So you need to apply `.map` function on the array you got, which is `completedata.records` in your current case.

And next issue you had is `data1 =`  inside the map function. On each iteration you are reassigning data1 to the new string ignoring all the previous iterations. You can achieve what you want by mapping your array of object to array of html strings and applying `.join` on this result array, which will produce the single html string.

```
fetch(
  "https://api.airtable.com/v0/appBTaX8XIvvr6zEC/tblYPd5g5k5IKIc98?api_key=##"
)
  .then((data) => data.json())
  .then((completedata) => {
    const html = completedata.records
      .map((values) => {
        return ` 
          <div class="card">
            <img src=${values.avatar} alt="Avatar" class="avatar">
            <p class="name">${values.Name}</p>
            <p class="occupation">${values.occupation}</p>
          </div>
        `;
      })
      .join("");
    document.getElementById("card").innerHTML = html;
  })
  .catch((error) => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```